# A query that does not work in Redshift for some reason

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Assuming the following sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
field1 varchar(50),
field2 varchar(50),
counter int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

and following data:

```
INSERT INTO test_data (field1, field2, counter) VALUES ('10','zyx',10);
INSERT INTO test_data (field1, field2, counter) VALUES ('10','mnb',2);
INSERT INTO test_data (field1, field2, counter) VALUES ('20','abc',15);
INSERT INTO test_data (field1, field2, counter) VALUES ('20','zyx',5);
INSERT INTO test_data (field1, field2, counter) VALUES ('20','mnb',1);
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
 SELECT field1, CASE
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 from ( SELECT x.field2 AS f
            FROM test_data AS x
            GROUP BY x.field2
            ORDER BY sum(x.counter) DESC
            LIMIT 2) as sub where y.field2 = sub.f) THEN y.field2
     ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
     END AS matched,
     sum(counter) as c
 FROM test_data AS y
 group by field1, matched;
```

This query runs fine in MySQL but I'm unable to make it run in Redshift which bombs out with the following:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error
```

Is there a viable, elegant work around ? I think it can be done with a temp table but I'm checking if there is not a better solution for that.

Comment: FWIW, Redshift is derived from PostgreSQL, not MySQL, so if you want to test queries on your local machine, use PostgreSQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm aware of that but I did not have a psql install handy so I just tried in mysql to see how it will handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate subquery and a join works in Redshift and the code is much cleaner (checked against MySQL result and got the same):

```
SELECT x.field1, coalesce(y.f,'UNKNOWN'), sum(counter) as c
FROM test_data x
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field2 AS f
    FROM test_data
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY sum(counter) DESC
    LIMIT 2
) y
ON x.field2=y.f
GROUP BY 1,2
```